# jQuery edit content of li element

Tags: jquery, html

I'm making simple todo list with jQuery and am stuck with a problem on how to edit the content of an `li` element by double clicking. I wrote a function, but it doesn't work.

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/strangeviking/1vwho2ru/3/:

```js
function addListItem() {
  var text = $('#new-text').val();
  $("#todolist").append('<li><input type="checkbox" class="edit" />' + text + ' <button class="delete">Delete</button></li>');
  $("#new-text").val('');
};

function deleteItem() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
}

function finishItem() {
  if ($(this).parent().css('textDecoration') == 'line-through') {
    $(this).parent().css('textDecoration', 'none')
  } else {

    $(this).parent().css('textDecoration', 'line-through');
  }
}

function editItem(e) {
  var $input = $(e.target).closest('li').addClass('editing').find('.edit');
  $input.val($input.val()).focus();
}

$(function() {
  $('#new-text').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      addListItem();
    }
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.delete', deleteItem);
  $(document).on('click', '.edit', finishItem);
  $(document).on('dblclick', '.edit', editItem);
  $("#select_all").click(function() {
    $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
    if ($('li').css('textDecoration') == 'line-through') {
      $('li').css('textDecoration', 'none')
    } else {

      $('li').css('textDecoration', 'line-through');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>List</h1>

<input type="text" id="new-text" />
<ul id="todolist"></ul>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="select_all" />Select all
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some other method to change element. Here is code:

```
var oriVal;
    $("#todolist").on('dblclick', 'span', function () {
        oriVal = $(this).text();
        $(this).text("");
        $("<input type='text'>").appendTo(this).focus();
    });
    $("#todolist").on('focusout', 'span > input', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.parent().text($this.val() || oriVal);
        $this.remove(); // Don't just hide, remove the element.
    });
```

It need some improvements, for example, to make editable visible while editing it, and submitting by pressing 'Enter', but it make it's basic function.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using doubleclick to edit, you can use HTML5's [`contenteditable`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp) attribute.

The change you'd make is to add a `span` around the text on this line:

```
$("#todolist").append('<li><input type="checkbox" class="edit" /> <span contenteditable="true">' + text + ' </span><button class="delete">Delete</button></li>');
```

```js
function addListItem() {
  var text = $('#new-text').val();
  $("#todolist").append('<li><input type="checkbox" class="edit" /><span contenteditable="true">' + text + ' </span><button class="delete">Delete</button></li>');
  $("#new-text").val('');
};

function deleteItem() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
}

function finishItem() {
  if ($(this).parent().css('textDecoration') == 'line-through') {
    $(this).parent().css('textDecoration', 'none')
  } else {

    $(this).parent().css('textDecoration', 'line-through');
  }
}

function editItem(e) {
  var $input = $(e.target).closest('li').addClass('editing').find('.edit');
  $input.val($input.val()).focus();
}

$(function() {
  $('#new-text').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      addListItem();
    }
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.delete', deleteItem);
  $(document).on('click', '.edit', finishItem);
  $(document).on('dblclick', '.edit', editItem);
  $("#select_all").click(function() {
    $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
    if ($('li').css('textDecoration') == 'line-through') {
      $('li').css('textDecoration', 'none')
    } else {

      $('li').css('textDecoration', 'line-through');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>List</h1>
<input type="text" id="new-text" />
<ul id="todolist">
</ul>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="select_all" />Select all
```

<sub>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1vwho2ru/4/)</sub>

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/3541881/%e1%94%95%e1%96%ba%e1%98%8e%e1%95%8a How can i can make it width limit only for text length ? I don't want to have possibility to delete checkboxes and buttons

Comment: @VasylPylypiv I don't understand you. If you add a `span` like I have in the example, you can't delete the checkbox/button - you can only edit the text.

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/3541881/%e1%94%95%e1%96%ba%e1%98%8e%e1%95%8a I'm sorry, I put this code in a wrong place. Now all working perfect. Would you help me with other tiny task related to this code ? I need to to write fucntion which will delete all checked elements

Comment: @VasylPylypiv If it is a different question, it would be better posted as a different question - otherwise it won't help other users! If THIS answer helped you, please +1 (by clicking the up arrow next to my answer) and accept (by clicking the tick mark just under the post score). Thanks :)